# I want to make a simple login for a library system in Java.How can I get the text field in the frame?

Tags: java, swing

I need a simple login page where a student can enter his/her credentials.But I'm not able to make the text field show up besides the username and the password to show up below the username.
This is the code I have written so far

```
package library;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class Loginpage {
private JPanel panel;
private JLabel label;
private JFrame frame;
private JTextField field;
/*Constructor*/public Loginpage(){
    gui();
}

    public void gui() {
    frame = new JFrame("WELCOME ");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds(500, 500, 500, 500);/*X axis,Y axis,Width,Height*/
    frame.setVisible(true);


    panel = new JPanel();
    label = new JLabel("Username");
    field = new JTextField(20);
    panel.add(label);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.add(label,BorderLayout.WEST);

    frame.add(field);


}

public static void main(String[]args){
    new Loginpage();

   }

 ``}
```

Comment: Btw you add `label` to two different container. It may lead to unexpected problems.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the setVisible(true) should always be put at the end, unless you want to display the output and then modify it, which is not the usual case.

If you mean you want this output:

### username: _____________ <--textfield

### password: _____________

Then you could try the GridLayout and divide the above output into four parts (2x2).

You can visit https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html for more details or https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/awt/gridlayout/java-gridlayout-example/ for examples.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are doing `frame.setVisible(true);` too early.

Try this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Loginpage {
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel label;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField field;

    /* Constructor */public Loginpage() {
        gui();
    }

    public void gui() {
        frame = new JFrame("WELCOME ");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(500, 500, 500, 500);/* X axis,Y axis,Width,Height */

        panel = new JPanel();
        label = new JLabel("Username");
        field = new JTextField(20);
        panel.add(label);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);

        frame.add(field);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Loginpage();

    }
    }
```

Also few other things:

- You might want to add `Layout` to your panel e.g. `panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());`
- Instead of adding `field` to `frame` by `frame.add(field);`, you should add it to `panel` by `panel.add(field);`
- Is this `frame.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);` really what you want? You can do this `panel.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);`. But this will show label to the right of text-field.

After these updates the code becomes this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Loginpage {
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel label;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField field;

    /* Constructor */public Loginpage() {
        gui();
    }

    public void gui() {
        frame = new JFrame("WELCOME ");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(500, 500, 500, 500);/* X axis,Y axis,Width,Height */

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        label = new JLabel("Username");
        field = new JTextField(20);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(field);
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Loginpage();

    }

}
```